# Passing several parameters as a single parameter in Java

Tags: java, parameters

I've seen an example of it before, but I've never really found any good reference material dealing with it.  I know it's possible to pass in several parameters, ints for example, by defining the method as

```
public void aMethod(int...a)
```

But I don't know any more about it than that.  I've seen an example, and it returned the average of the ints passed.
Is this an out-dated way of passing parameters?  Is it even acceptable to use this?  What exactly is the syntax like when doing this? 
(Some reference material would be great)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's called varargs (from the C syntax).  See [Sun's varargs guide](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) for an overview and this [JDC Tech Tip](http://java.sun.com/developer/JDCTechTips/2005/tt0104.html) for usage. It is not out-dated; it was put in as a feature request since previously you were forced to create an array or list, which was really ugly for supporting something like C's printf.

```
public void myMethod(String... args) {
    for (String aString:args) {
        System.out.println(aString);
    }
}
```

Comment: As to when to use it, varargs does come with a performance penalty. So only use it when you really have to use it. I've encountered precious little problems in java where I thought 'man, I could really use varargs here' (only printf comes to mind)

Answer (score -1):

You are going to have to pass a list of `ints` to the method to do this, something like this:

```
public void aMethod(int[] list)
```

or this:

```
public void aMethod(ArrayList<int> list)
```

It would be nice if Java had something like C#'s `params` keyword but it doesn't.

Comment: The whole point of the "varargs" notation is that you DON'T have to pass an explicit array or list.

Comment: I am not much of a Java guy so I had no idea this existed! Good to know!